# What was slang for "absentminded" or "empty headed" before "space cadet"?

Tags: slang

What was slang for "absentminded" or "empty headed" before "space cadet"?
[image: space cadet]

Comment: Considering I've never heard of `space cadet` as slang for that term, a very vast number of terms spring to mind.

Comment: -1 *space cadet* is not widely known as a set-phrase. It is not slang for *absent-minded*, it seems. OP is not clear if what is needed is a slang term for *absent-minded* or a suitable replacement for *space cadet*.

Comment: Space cadet means empty headed, not absent minded.

Comment: How old is *airhead* ?

Comment: I disagree with @pazzo — a head filled with impracticalities is not empty.

Answer (score 5):

How about "scatterbrain", seemingly from [1790](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=scatterbrain)?
Or "hare-brained" from ca. [1540](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=hare-brained)?

Although, it's hard to trust those figures without sources.

Comment: Seeing the title, I came here to add hare-brained, though I've usually read it in the context, "... and his hare-brained schemes ...", which might rather imply *ridiculous* rather than absentminded.

Comment: [1726](http://books.google.fi/books?id=m5lUAAAAYAAJ&q=scatterbrains#v=snippet&q=scatterbrains&f=false) and [1786](http://books.google.fi/books?id=uyQJAAAAQAAJ&q=scatterbrain#v=snippet&q=scatter%20brain&f=false) *scatterbrains*, and [1588](http://www.archive.org/stream/characteriearteo00brig#page/n135/mode/2up) *harebrained*. The Online Etymology Dictionary is quite reliable for dates, and you can email to ask for sources.

Answer (score 2):

Woolly-headed comes to my mind.

There seems to be a number of uses for absent-minded beyond the usual 'forgetful' - and plenty of synonyms:

http://thesaurus.com/browse/absent-minded

Comment: **Wool-gathering** ... I haven't heard that for a while.